# Custom Font Not Working On Android Device Corona SDK

Tags: android, fonts, lua, coronasdk

I have been developing a mobile game using the Corona SDK. I love this framework and it's very easy for me to use. However, I've recently been having a problem with custom fonts. I'm using an Android device.

When I load the game onto the simulator, the font I'm using works great. But when I load the game on my device, the font doesn't show up and it uses the device's default font. I'm not sure what to do. I know you don't have to include anything in the `build.settings` file. I am completely stumped.

Here is the font I am using. It's a font I created myself using http://myscriptfont.com.

Download - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwZL696qLhk3eTloVVZXUFF3RU0/view?usp=sharing

I understand that it is an OpenType Font but I just renamed it from a TrueType. I have suspicions that the problem is my font but I haven't gotten around to testing the game with other fonts.

Comment: put font name correctly with case sensitive.

Comment: @AndroidUser I did. It works in the simulator.

Comment: did you put that font file in your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I have to have my font in the root folder of the project and not in any other folders.